# how to handle data from asyntask - need pojo

Tags: java, android

i am calling this [api](http://iwg-testapi.azurewebsites.net/stem/funds/1) in my android app , in which json is returned with many different fields. How can I get this into a pojo ? I am using an asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to create your model. then you can use Retrofit with Json to grab this data. here is a good tutorial and example.
**[Consuming APIs with Retrofit](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit)**